# How do I use BIRT in an RCP application without using the BIRT runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, birt

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have an eclipse plugin that contains certain data (actually Strings representing the file structure of a project). These Strings are acesssible over usual getters and are stored in Lists. I now want to put these Strings into BIRT to get a *pdf* or *html*. From what I found out so far, I will need to integrate BIRT in the plugin somehow (I do **not** want to have to select a data source and data set and so on like you'd have to using BIRD's UI - this should happen automatically in my code). Further, I wouldn't like to use the **BIRT runtime**, but only the normal jars you get from the common installation way over *eclispe->help->istall new software*. Is that even possible without the runtime **and** without digging really deep in the BIRT source files? I am actually looking for something like:

```
Datasource source = new DataSource();
/* put somehow the strings into the data source */
DataSet set = new DataSet();
/* connect set to source, create layout and so on */
```

This is the mthod I'm currently working in:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    /* the strings are accessible over "fs" */
    FileStructure fs = extractFileStructure(event);

    /* TODO: Implement the layout */
}
```

I hope my question's clear enough :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to answer this question myself, so I'm going to answer it in case someone has the same problem.
Actually my question was slightly silly because I didn't really know what I was talking about. I don't think it's very wise to try to implement this without using the **BIRT runtime**. What I was talking about was the installation of the BIRT runtime environment (where you had to set a HOME variable and so on) which was only necessary before version 3.7 of BIRT. Now you can just skip this step which is exactly what I wanted. Actually it's not such a big deal. All the information I needed could be found in this [eclipse tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportEngineAPI.php). But I recommend you not to copy the code straight away because the tutorial seems to be a little older, so some of the methods used there are deprecated in the current BIRT version (they actually might have been disappeared if you read this post later).
I hope that this was/is helpful for some of you. :)